# javascript design pattern on page with 2 or more objects

Tags: javascript, oop, object, design-patterns

I need to choose the right design pattern. My page have 2 objects created from same constructor. The problem that i have is detecting which object is getting a click event.

I am doing this after object creation:

```
$("table tr, table button,.dataTables_paginate a").click(function (e) {
    **myTableName.buttonPressed($(this));**

});
```

and

```
 buttonPressed: function (el) {
    if (el.is('a') && el.closest('li').hasClass('paginate_button')) {
        var objName = el.attr('aria-controls');
        debugger;
    }
    else {
        var objName = $(el).closest('table').attr('id');
    }

    **this.getName(objName);**
    tbl = myTableName.tbl;
    editor = myTableName.editor;
    //myTableName.acl(myTableName.currentForm);

},
```

and then

```
 getName: function (objName) {
    // search through the global object for a name that resolves to this object
    for (var name in window)
        if (window[name] == this) {
            if (objName) {
                myTableName = window[objName];
                //window.myState[this.myInstanceName] = jQuery.extend({}, this);
                break;
            } else {
                window[name] = this;
                window[window[name]] = window[name];
                myTableName = window[window[name]];
                // window.myState[this.myInstanceName] = jQuery.extend({}, this);
            }
            break;
        }
},
```

Besides these are all globals , i dont fell this is the correct way to do that.

Thoughts?

Comment: Your code and question are not very clear. What do you mean by "my page has 2 objects"? If you are trying to identify what triggered the click event, you have two options: create separate event handlers for each selector, or detect what selector triggered the event inside a single event handler that handles all clicks. Also, what is "name"? A selector? The value of the `name` attribute? The ID or node type? If you could clear up your intentions it would help greatly.

Comment: sorry. 2 objects were created:

Comment: sorry. 2 objects were created:      var qTableIdent = new QuadTable();
    qTableIdent.initTable(options); var qTableDocs = new QuadTable();     qTableIdent.initTable(options2);    options and options2 are extensive objects . 'name' is the instance name that is also the container id or an atribute if the click is on paginate element.   buttonPressed: function (el) {
    if (el.is('a') && el.closest('li').hasClass('paginate_button')) {
        var objName = el.attr('aria-controls');
        debugger;
    }
    else {
        var objName = $(el).closest('table').attr('id');
    }

Comment: Another aproach might be the mvc pattern off course,but, as i m not using frameworks....

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you for clearing that up, I understand a little more now :) So I take it you just need a place to store your table objects and refer to them using a name? I won't post this as an answer yet because I'm still not fully clear, but at the most basic level, you can create a global object called `tables` or something, and then add tables to them like so: `tables[name] = quadTableInstance;`. To get a table, simply access the property value using its key: `table = tables[name];`.

Comment: If you're worried about using globals, you can create a new object as a new property in your current object called 'tables', and use that instead.

Comment: allready do that:    qTableIdent.tbl = $('#' + options.tableId).DataTable(dtOptions);
    qTableIdent.editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
        //ajax: "/QUAD_HCM/data-source/" + options.sqlFile,
        ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
            myTableName.getData(myTableName.initState, this);
        },
        table: "#" + myTableName.tableId,
        idSrc: 'RHID',
        fields: $.grep(myTableName.tableCols, function (e) {
            if (e.name)
                return e.name;
        }),
      ...

Comment: addEvents:function(){
        debugger;
     
        tbl = myTableName.tbl;
        editor = myTableName.editor;       tbl.on('page.dt', function () {

            if (myTableName.serverSideProcessing) {
                var info = tbl.page.info();
                myTableName.startIn = info.page * myTableName.recordBundle;
                myTableName.initState = false;
                tbl.page(info.page).draw(false);
            }
        });            http://www.quad-systems.pt/QUAD_HCM/#ajax/datatableMasterDetal.php

Comment: I think using custom attributes could solve your problem? You could set the instance ID/name/whatever as the value of an attribute called `data-table-instance-name` or whatever on each table in the DOM, so that when you get the element in jQuery, you can get the name without having to check through all instances/names.

Comment: True, i agree on that

Comment: I have added an answer to explain further.

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos: Please put your code in your question - you can [edit] it - instead of posting it as comments

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should use custom attributes. Custom attributes allow you to store additional relevant data to any DOM element. One way this could be used would be to associate the DOM with some JS bytecode. This is especially useful when you have to work backwards, i.e. finding the relevant object(s) to the HTML element. The standard says that these attributes must start with `data-` (although technically you could use anything not used by the browser, but this is not advised). Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<table data-instance-name="name1">
    ...
    <button>Action</button>
    <a>Another action</a>
</table>
<table data-instance-name="name2">
    ...
    <button>Action</button>
    <a>Another action</a>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$( 'table button, table a' ).on('click', function() {
    var name = $(this).closest('table').attr('data-instance-name'),
        table = tables[name];
});
```